# pagination with php with a possible infinite limit

Tags: php, pagination

I know how to create pagination with php if I have 25 results with 5 results each page, but what about if the limit number can change in the hundreds everyday? How can I write something where the php itself will create more pages if the row count itself changes?

Answer (score 0):

usually pagination is made in two steps:

- query to count the number of records
- unsig the prevoius query, create the query using LIMIT to retrieve the current page

So i don't see the problem o_O, if tomorrow the number of elements change then the first query would return a different result.. and you wont have problems with the pagination

Later, if you want to improve performance you could set a cache system for the `count` query.

Hope this helps